# How to build static datePicker widget in Flutter, without the need to press a button before

Tags: flutter, datepicker

I want to build a static DatePicker with Flutter, without the need to press a button before. When the screen loads it should display the picker. Tried flutter-cupertino-date-picker. Tried flutter_datetime_picker 1.2.0. Tried Flutter examples on github.

I tried CupertinoDatePicker without gesture detector but it fails, only works pressing a button before.

```
Widget _buildDatePicker(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        showCupertinoModalPopup<void>(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return _buildBottomPicker(
              CupertinoDatePicker(
                mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
                initialDateTime: date,
                onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newDateTime) {
                  setState(() => date = newDateTime);
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
      child: _buildMenu(<Widget>[
        const Text('Date'),
        Text(
          DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(date),
          style: const TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.inactiveGray),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
```

expected: static date picker on load screen
actual: Button showed that displays the date picker on press

Answer (score 2):

`CupertinoDatePicker` is a widget, which means it can be added as a child widget to any other widgets that has a `child` property. If you want to show a `CupertinoDatePicker` on your screen you can do it as follow:

```
 return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: CupertinoDatePicker(
          mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
          initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
          onDateTimeChanged: (dateTime) {
            debugPrint("$dateTime");
          },
        ));
```

Note: you'll have to customise the layout to fit your requirements, this is just a sample on how to display a date picker without pressing a button.

Answer (score 0):

Since your date picker is a separate widget in itself, you can just call the widget inside the build method on your main screen where the date picker has to be shown. For example :

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  _buildDatePicker(context);
  return Scaffold(
    //your screen where the date picker must be shown
);
}
```