# How to create calendar flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNTJ8.png)

> how to create calendar in flutter scrollable like in the picture. I tried find some plugins but cant found!

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoDatePicker-class.html . This is 
a CupertinoDatePicker.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build static datePicker widget in Flutter, without the need to press a button before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56073342/how-to-build-static-datepicker-widget-in-flutter-without-the-need-to-press-a-bu)

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can Check this package
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_calendar_nullsafety